# ¿Cuál es el verbo para "party" en español?

Tags: verbos

¿Cómo se dice "I want to party tonight"?
Yo sé que se puede decir "Quiero ir a una fiesta esta noche", pero estoy buscando un *verbo* que tenga el mismo efecto.

Comment: Quiero [fiestear](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=fiestear) esta noche, aunque en Cuba usamos mucho party la gente joven, **Quiero irme de party esta noche**

Comment: En ingles, "Party" significa cosas varios: {A hooker asks if you want to "party"} utiliza una interpretación diferente de {Some colleagues ask if you want to go "party" after work}.

Comment: You can print an "ñ" easily (in windows at least) using key combo: ALT+164 (using the num key pad). ALT+165 -> "Ñ"... just a tip ;) (I cringe everytime I see a "cumpleanos"...)

Comment: También se puede decir: "Quiero ir de fiesta esta noche"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Parrandear" es la traducción más correcta de "party" en el sentido de "to go out and party" o "you party all day long".

"Festejar" significa lo mismo que "celebrar", como "to have a party".

Answer (score 11):

"[Festejar](http://dle.rae.es/festejar)".

Translating your example, it would end up being something like:

> ¡Esta noche quiero festejar!

You can also use "Celebrar", which translates to "Celebrate". It depends on the context. For this particular translation, I'd go with "Festejar".

**EDIT**

Please note that this answer is not aimed at a particular region, but instead, it's meant to be understood in any region, taking as reference the [RAE](http://www.rae.es/), and taking into account that the question does not specify any location. As noted in the comments, it may be subject for misunderstandings in some places.

Comment: I think this is the answer. The others would be right if  slang had been asked.

Comment: I don't agree. The first meanings of "[festejar](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=festejar)" are "Celebrar algo con fiestas" and "Hacer festejos en obsequio de alguien"; in both cases, the emphasis is on the "something" that's celebrated, or in the someone that receives the celebration; at least in Argentina (and, I suspect, in many other places) the word is used in those senses. To mean "I want to party tonight" we'd never say "Quiero festejar" but "Quiero ir/salir de fiesta".

Comment: @leonbloy of course, but the OP is asking for an alternative to that expression. Which non-regional verbs would be able to express that? Moreover the last meaning is, after all, a meaning. Why would the first meanings appearing there be better?

Comment: @leonbloy I don't think the order of the meanings are relevant in this case, but maybe I'm wrong. As for the context, I wanted to answer with a word that would be understood in any region, if such thing is possible, and that would also be suitable for a translation. I don't know about Argentina but correct me if I'm wrong: Would anyone misunderstand if you said "Quiero festejar"?

Comment: > Would anyone misunderstand if you said "Quiero festejar"? Here (Argentina) it would sound wrong; nobody would use that in that sense; and everybody would spontaneously ask: "¿Festejar qué?". The young people just say "salir".

Comment: @leonbloy Does that qualify as a complete misunderstanding? Would anyone in Argentina read a text that says "¡Esta noche quiero festejar!", the response affirms "¡Suena bien, yo llevo las bebidas!", and ask about what that means?

Comment: @ArthurChamz He/she would still ask: "¿Qué se festeja?" ("What is the celebration about?"). I'd call that a misunderstanding.

Comment: @leonbloy I really don't believe someone would be confused if they were to read a text like that, and even it that were the case, I'd argue that's an incorrect use of the language from the listener, because the meaning of the word is clear as seen in it's definition. Given that neither "[ir](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=ir)" or "[salir](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=salir)" have any meanings in the RAE for partying, I still think "Festejar" is the best choice.

Comment: Creo que festejar se puede prestar a confusion como explican arriba, el verbo mas neutral seria [fiestear](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=fiestear). Yo siempre he dicho fiestar ahora que lo busque vi que se escribia distinto

Comment: Aceptar términos coloquiales es demasiado inapropiado. Creo que el usuario que pregunta debería solicitar de dónde específicamente necesita el término para apuntar mejor su texto. Si es una campaña de marketing lo mejor sería utilizar el término del país respectivo.

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo @Claudiordgz

Comment: ¡Hurra por @Claudiordgz!

Comment: I voted to close the question as too broad, deberiamos educarnos o educar a los nuevos visitantes que cuando preguntan un termino deben referirse a una locacion especifica, ya que el castellano varia mucho hasta dentro de cada pais, seria bueno debatir esto en http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I made a question regarding this situation in meta: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/345/answering-questions-with-unspecified-region

Comment: Well, the thing here @EmilioGort, is that *festejar* and *celebrar* might be quite universally accepted. I personaly think this answer is suficient, which I shown upovoting. To me it is not clear the line between questions which should include a tag "regional differences" and those which don´t.

Comment: @c.p. yo podría estar de acuerdo, yo lo entendería bien, pero por alla arriba dicen que en argentina traería confusión. Y tiene su lógica no crees. yo tambien di mi upvote, pero la question es otra como vez siempre este tipo de preguntas traen debates, mejor continuar en el chat o en http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/345/answering-questions-with-unspecified-region

Answer (score 8):

Otras posibilidades:

- Ir/Salir de fiesta
- Ir/Salir de marcha
- Ir/Salir de copas
- Ir salir de juerga
- Ir/Salir de parranda

y en algunos contextos, simplemente "salir" es suficiente:

- ¡Por fin es viernes! ¡Esta noche salimos!

Comment: +1 Tambien, "salir de copas".

Comment: would you use reflexive here, like would it be me voy de fiesta/parranda or just voy  de fiesta/parranda

Comment: @user3163829 To my ear, both sound correct. I would use *"voy a ir de fiesta"* when I'm planning to do something, and  *"me voy de fiesta"* otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Festejar,
pero los Colombianos dicen "rumbear", o sea, irse de Rumba o de fiesta.

Answer (score 4):

Depende del país.

En Colombia oirás "rumbear", mientras que en México se usa "reventarse" y en España "ir de fiesta".

Comment: In spain also: "Irse de farra", "de parranda", "¿Fiesta, que fiesta? ¡La que te va a dar esta!"

Comment: Soy de México y eso de "reventarse", no sé dónde se usa, pero en el bajío, centro y norte de México (que es dónde he vivido) no se usa.

Acá sería: "Hoy quiero ir de fiesta". Aunque si es más en sentido de "rumbear" cómo en Colombia, sería más bien: "agarrar el pedo" o "agarrar la peda" (si esto involucra alcohol, ir a bailar y demás).

Comment: @Omar *reventarse* es muy usado, se me hace muy raro que alguien no lo reconozca.

Comment: @c.p. si lo reconozco, pero pues no se usa "Vamos a reventarnos" (a menos que veas la rosa de Guadalupe o algún programa así de malo), en todo caso es "Vámonos de reven" o "Vámonos al reventón", pero casi no se usa, se usaba en los 90's.

Answer (score 4):

En Chile se dice 'carretear', pero si quieres ser más neutro 'festejar' me parece mejor.

Answer (score 4):

Es también posible decir "Quiero irme de juerga".

Answer (score 4):

La palabra que tu buscas en mi tierra se dice de la siguiente manera

PEDAAAAAAAAAAAAA

que significa irnos de juerga, irnos de peda

En México sólo la gritas y todos te entenderán

Creo que si festear es válido, también peda

Comment: +1 "Vamos a agarrar el pedo", agregaría yo, al menos en Monterrey se usa mucho.

Comment: Pachanguear tambien se usa en méxico.

Answer (score 1):

En el norte de México, se escucha muy seguido "pistear" en sentido de "to go out and party" especialmente cuando se trata de visitar a muchos lugares distintos.