# ¿Qué significa "maluco" en el castellano colombiano?

Tags: significado, colombia

¿Qué significa exactamente "maluco"? He oído muchas veces esta palabra en Colombia (Antioquia) pero no pude encontrarla en ningun diccionario.

¿Es simplemente sinónimo con "malo" o qué?

Comment: *-uco* es uno de los muchos diminutivos que tiene el castellano, entonces, a menos que tenga algún significado particular en Colombia (dejo a que uno de los colombianos nos lo aclare), es casi igual a decir *malito*, tal vez con un un pequeño sentido despectivo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bogotálogo es el mejor lugar donde buscar estas definiciones : )

> [**Maluco**](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital)
>
> 1. Dícese de quien padece cierto tipo de malestar.
> 2. De mal sabor.

El DRAE también tiene una entrada, si bien menciona siempre Venezuela como el país donde se usa y con una definición algo alejada de la Colombiana:

> [**maluco**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O52c9NY%7CO532Dhj)<sup>2</sup>, ca
>
> 1. adj. coloq. malucho.
> 2. adj. Ven. Dicho de una persona: Ingrata y malvada.
> 3. adj. Ven. Dicho de un objeto: De poca calidad o eficacia.
> 4. adj. Ven. Dicho de un alimento: De gusto desagradable.

Como estas definiciones son algo sucintas, veo algo más descriptivo lo dicho en la entrada de blog [Definición y significados de "Maluco"](http://porquenosisi.blogspot.com.es/2008/08/definicin-y-significados-de-maluco.html):

> Maluco: adjetivo usado en la costa y el interior de Colombia (al menos
>   no se lo he oído a más gente de por ahí) para señalar lo repugnante,
>   repulsiva o asquerosa que puede ser una cosa, situación o persona.
>   Bien, esa era la definición, ahora el significado en pocas o una sola
>   palabra, es decir maluco = maluco ( ¡Ajá car'e verga!).

También el Diccionario de americanismos lo define:

> [**maluco, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=qfk7q8a1sx0AY9M0RDH%7C9ZktkhDSVx0A39MDiTa).
>   II. 1.  adj. Ni, Co, Ve, Bo. Referido a cosa, desagradable a los sentidos del gusto o del olfato. pop + cult → espon.
>   2.  Co, Bo. Desagradable a la vista o al gusto estético. pop.

Donde `II. 1.` aplica a Nicaragua, Colombia, Venezuela y Bolivia y `II. 2` a Colombia y Bolivia.

En mi experiencia, se utiliza en situaciones como (compañeros colombianos en el sitio -léase DGaleano y Joze-, corríjanme si no atino):

> - Esta situación está muy maluca: el presidente del gobierno es
>   corrupto y la oposición también.
>
> - Ayer [rumbeé](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5255/1674) y hoy estoy muy maluco: el guayabo no me deja
>   levantarme
>   <sub>(Ayer salí de fiesta y estoy muy malo: la resaca me está
>   matando)</sub>

Comment: Iba a publicar mi propia respuesta, pero me descubro ante la tuya. Tan sólo añadir que, curiosamente, aquí en Andalucía (España) se dice a veces _me noto malusquillo_, que es una vuelta de tuerca del término _maluco_ para decir que te encuentras raro, pero no tanto como para decir que estás mal.

Comment: Qué interesante, @CarlosAlejo . ¿Decís _malu**s**quillo_, con la "s"? La verdad es que escribiendo la respuesta me di cuenta de que la línea que separa _maluco_ de un diminutivo de _malo_ es fina, seguramente esté perdiendo algún matiz que de buen seguro algún usuario colombiano sabrá explicar.

Comment: Efectivamente, con la 's'. [Aquí](http://pasoscontados.com/copy_of_no-rutas/palabrario) tienes un enlace que he encontrado con vocabulario típico de la zona que incluye esa palabra y muchas más.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo menuda joya has encontrado. Casi ninguna de las palabras me suena y encuentro alguna tan curiosa como _follapepe_, _liquindoi_, _tenguerengue_. Curioso que tengáis _huevón_ con otro significado, luego _meco_ la usamos en catalán. _Mijilla_ parece un doble diminutivo. _Niqui_ yo creo que debe venri de algún nombre comercial (como las _bambas_, de Wamba). _Rebujina_ lo oí como _rebujito_ en Málaga. Y qué bueno que digáis _Yanito_ y no _llanito_. Lo dicho, una joya.

Comment: Pues si te gusta el tema, te recomiendo el libro "El habla de Cádiz", donde se revisan todas esas expresiones y se les intenta dar explicación. Yo soy de Sevilla, que está al lado, y la mayoría tampoco me suenan a mí. De hecho mi mujer es de esa zona y al principio a veces necesitaba traducción para según qué expresiones...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡caramba! Si cuando hablamos aquí de [tag:diferencias-regionales] las que hay entre regiones de España merecerían muchas preguntas también. Me alegra que haya tantas diferencias, es interesantísimo saltar de pueblo en pueblo viendo tanto cambio. Yo recuerdo pasear por Castilla y apenas entender lo que decía la gente de los pueblos. Tengo pendiente la zona de Cádiz; por lo que veo, será una tarea ardua : )

Comment: Perfecta respuesta. La información del "bogotálogo" no incluye las acepciones 2, 3 y 4 de DRAE porque son expresiones más "caribeñas" por lo que DRAE las ubica en Venezuela pero se usan de igual manera en toda la región caribe de Colombia.  La primera (malucho) nunca la he oído y todas menos esa son de uso común en Antioquia.

Comment: @DGaleano qué bien, ¡gracias! Dudaba de si me estaba dejando algo. Así pues, la respuesta no es maluca ;-)

Answer (score 0):

En colombia es sinónimo de Feo ejemplo: !ue tipo tan feo y como adjetivo, sentirse mal ejemplo: Me siento maluco.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.