# ¿"Zapping" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

Cuando uno está mirando la tele, con frecuencia se aburre y recurre al *zapping*. Esto es, a ir pasando de un canal a otro para intentar encontrar contenidos más interesantes.

Zapping es la palabra inglesa y veo que el DRAE ha aceptado "zapear" y "zapeo":

> [**zapear**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cN4njNd%7CcN8G1vz)<sup>2</sup>
>
> 1. intr. Practicar el zapeo.
>
> [**zapeo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cNHAID8)
>
> Adapt. del ingl. *zapping*.
>
> 1. m. Cambio reiterado de canal de televisión por medio del mando a distancia.

Así que fantástico. Pero así y todo me chirría tener que utilizar un anglicismo. ¿Hay alguna palabra española que signifique lo mismo? Se me ocurre *(h)ojear*, *explorar* o *navegar* (más o menos, la traducción de *browse*), pero ninguna de ellas me gusta del todo. ¿Se os ocurre alguna traducción más acertada o podemos dejarlo en *zapear* sin más?

Comment: Para serte honesto, fedorqui, yo siempre he usado «brincando» o «saltando», p. ej., «Llevo una hora brincando/saltando de canal en canal y aún no hallo nada que me interese lo suficiente». No digo que sea lo “correcto”, pero es la que me gusta. ¡Saludos!

Comment: ... y para hacer eco a @TeachingTom lo que hemos usado siempre en mi familia es "Llevo una hora **saltado canales** y no encuentro nada interesante". Es un poco más corto que "saltando de canal en canal" pero esencialmente es lo mismo y por lo menos no es anglicismo.

Comment: @DGaleano, esa también se usa en mi país («Llevo una hora saltando canales»). ¡Qué fascinante es el uso de la lengua!

Comment: @TeachingTom entonces la propondré como respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La práctica a la que se refiere la pregunta es tan antigua como la televisión misma incluso antes de que éstos aparatos tuvieran "control remoto" (o mando a distancia como lo llaman en otros lugares) y como dicha práctica se comenzó a usar antes de que el anglicismo *zapping* nos llegara, la comenzamos a llamar **"saltar canales"**.

En caso de querer utilizar nuestro querido idioma sin utilizar anglicismos, esta es una muy buena alternativa.

> "Llevo una hora **saltando canales** y no encuentro nada interesante"

o alternativamente

> "Llevo una hora **saltando de canal en canal** y no encuentro nada interesante"

Comment: ¡Me gusta lo que sugieres! Además, con la calidad actual de los canales, a veces dan más ganas de _asaltarlos_ ;-)

Comment: Por cierto, me interesa mucho saber tu opinión sobre [esta respuesta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16979/1674): ¿atiné definiendo _maluco_?

Comment: ¿"Saltado" o "saltando"?

Comment: Tienes razón @Yay . Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Creo que alguna vez he usado la expresión *[sondeo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YMEE1Oj) de canales*, dado que el propósito del *zapeo* es ver si echan algo interesante en algún canal. Por tanto, se pueden sondear los canales tal y como indica la acepción, para hacer las primeras averiguaciones sobre algo (lo que están echando), antes de decidir con qué te quedas.

Lo que pasa es que me da que el *zapeo* puede implicar una acción compulsiva además de reiterada, connotación de la cual carece un simple sondeo.

Comment: ¡Interesante sugerencia! Me gusta, si bien me quedo con lo sugerido por DGaleano porque el _saltar_ me parece algo más superficial que _sondear_, por lo que está más cerca de esa actividad algo desatenta que es el zapear.

Answer (score 0):

En Colombia el término que usamos es "Canalear" derivado de la palabra canal de TV.