# What is a proper translation for "party hard"? (or "hard" and an adjective)

Tags: traducción, adjetivos

In ¿[Cuál es el verbo para “party” en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5236/5481) we considered some possible translations for party as a verb. Among them: *festejar, parrandear, salir* (de copas/ de marcha/ de fiesta...) etc.

But what happens if we add the adjective "hard", as in the expression "party hard"? The literal translation for "hard" in Spanish would be "duro", but you won't use that in all context. For example, you would translate

> You need to work *hard* to earn your wage

as "hay que trabajar duro para ganarse el sueldo". For

> I have been working *hard*.

You may favor "mucho" instead of "duro". In addition

> I am a *hard* working person

Would be translated as "Soy una persona trabajadora".

Just translating "hard" as "duro" could lead to may anglicisms in many contexts.

Thus said, what happens if we try to translate "party hard"? "Party hard" means to do the things you usually do at a party (dance, eat good food, drink alcohol, etc.) and to do them to excess, with intensity, etc.

But "festejar/parrandear/salir *en exceso/excesivamente*" don't really convey "party hard". It may convey frequency rather than intensity.

What if I wanted to translate for example

> I like to work **hard** and party **hard**.

or

> I like to work **hard** and party **harder**.

How could I translate "party hard"? Just simply "me gusta festejar/salir en exceso"?

Comment: Se me ocurre "salir a partirla" pero igual es una expresión demasiado coloquial y regional

Comment: Creo que "duro" funciona perfectamente en todos tus ejemplos, y no suena a inglés: *Trabajo duro y festejo duro*.

Comment: @Javier "festejo duro" a mí sí me suena a anglicismo. Creo que por lo menos en España sería muy raro escucharlo. Quizá también porque en España se favorecerían otros términos para "party" como verbo que no cuadran tan bien con "duro". En qué región decís "festejar duro"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"**Darlo todo**" or "**dándolo todo**" is a way of saying that you are going hard at some task. You could also say "**a tope**". Both are informal; the first one a bit less than the last one.

Translating some of your examples:

> "We partied hard last night."
>   → *"Salimos dándolo todo anoche."*
>   → *"Salimos a tope anoche."*
>
> Sometimes even *"Lo dimos todo anoche."* would be understood in the right context.

> "I like to work hard and party harder."
>   → *"En el trabajo lo doy todo, y de fiesta todo y más."*
>   → *"Me gusta trabajar a tope y salir de fiesta más a tope aún."*

Comment: I would go with `con todo`.

Comment: Where I grew up (Argentina), putting "anoche" at the end of the sentence sounds weird: it sounds like spanglish.  And "a tope" would be understood but again sound weird.